# Cellular automata with different generating-cells configuration

Tags: cellular-automata

I recently faced the problem of generating "interesting" binary matrices for testing a heuristics for the $3DCC$-problem, i.e. to check if the graph represented by the adjacency matrix contains a vertex-disjoint cycle cover without pairs of antiparallel arcs.

Eventually I had the idea to resort to cellular automata, especially the ones with "Wolfram rules" 110, 124, 137 and 193 that are universal Turing machines ([Agapie, Andreica, Chira, and Giuclea - Predictability in Cellular Automata](https://doi.org/10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0108177)).

However the fact that the automata color new cells row by row didn't seem desirable to me and after a while I found a way to make the automata color new cells parallel to the (anti-)diagonal when seeding a corner of the matrix.

Whereas in the "classical" way cell $(i,j)$ depends on cells $(i-1,j-1)$, $(i-1,j)$ and $(i-1,j+1)$, in new way $(i,j)$ depends on cells $(i,j-1)$, $(i-1,j-1)$ and $(i-1,j)$ when seeding the upper left cell of the matrix.

[image: classical vs new configuration of generating cells depicted in gray]

An implication of the new angular arrangement of the generating cells is however that the coloring of cells depends on the previous two generations.

> **Question:**
>
> have angular arrangements of the generating cells of cellular automats already been investigated, maybe even in higher dimensions, where the color of exactly one $1\times1\times\dotsb\times1$ hypercell of an $2\times2\times\dotsb\times2$ hypercubic arrangement of hypercells depends on the colors of the other $2\times2\times\dotsb\times2-1$ hypercells?

Comment: Currently uploding images doesn't work; I will provide an illustration as soon as the server is up again

Comment: One classical way to generate reversible CA is related https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cellular_automaton